# Postgres import from pg_dump throws error of none existing character: syntax error at or near "ÿ_"

Tags: postgresql, powershell, pg-dump

My first post here may go a bit against the grain - if it does violate guidelines feel free to delete. The problem itself has been solved, but since it was quite frustrating and the solution is documented nowhere, however simple it is, I thought I post here for fellow devs encountering the same. Beyond that, if someone can shed some light as to why this happened in the first place, Answers are more than welcome.

**The Issue**

- Downloading data from local PostgreSQL instance using `pg_dump` from a DB1
- ```
  Full command: pg_dump -U {user} -d {sourceDB} -t {sourceTable} > {dump}.sql
  ```
- Uploading the data on the same server in a different DB2 using `psql`
- ```
  Full command: psql -U {user} -d {targetDB} -f {dump}.sql
  ```
- On Import, the following error is thrown

```
    psql:tbl_strainsLog.sql:1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ÿ_"  LINE 1: ÿ_-
        ^
```

While the error may seem intuitive, there is no such character anywhere in the file.
I had tried multiple different options for export and the import, all throw the same issue.
Encoding of source & target DB were set to UTF8, collation was en_US.utf8 on both as well.
I checked the initially loaded data, encoding was UTF8 there as well.

**SETUP**

- Windows 10
- Powershell
- Postgres 13

Thanks, and I a m very curious if anyone has deeper insights as to what causes this issue in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

So the culprit for the issue seems `Powershell` itself. While I have no exact knowledge of why this would happen, bypassing Powershell did the trick.

If I either run the above commands from `cmd` or I "pipe" the`pg_dump` command through `cmd.exe`, the error disappears and it works flawlessly.

So either...

A) in `cmd` run `pg_dump -U {user} -d {sourceDB} -t {sourceTable} > {dump}.sql`
or

B) in `Powershell` run `& cmd.exe /c "pg_dump -U {user} -d {sourceDB} -t {sourceTable} > {dump}.sql"`

This resolves the encoding issue created by pure Powershell during the export/dump.
The import works fine in `Powershell`, so the encoding issue only applies during export.

Hope this helps people struggeling with the same.

Comment: I think `>` defaults to writing UTF16, at least in the Windows version of Powershell. The `ÿ` is probably part of the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding). `psql` should be OK with a UTF8 BOM, so you could write it with [`Out-File -Encoding utf8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-File?view=powershell-5.1), but the simplest solution is probably to use `-f {dump}.sql` and let `pg_dump` write the file itself.